How do I randomly upper-case words in an array in Powershell?
I currently have the following code in my script:
$array1 = @("Car", "House", "Computer", "Phone")
$array1 = $array1 | Get-Random -Count 2

Write-Host $array1

This works and I'm still learning and have the following question: How would I randomly have one of the two words be set in uppercase?
I tried the following, $array1 = $array1.ToUpper() | Get-Random -Count 2, but that just displayed both of them in upper case
Thank you very much for your time.

One way to do it would be to get and update an item by random index:
$array1 = @("Car", "House", "Computer", "Phone")
$array1 = $array1 | Get-Random -Count 2
$index = Get-Random -Maximum $array1.Length
$array1[$index] = $array1[$index].ToUpper()
$array1

# COMPUTER
# Phone

Following this logic, you could use Update-TypeData to extend the System.Array type with a ScriptMethod:
$updateTypeDataSplat = @{
    TypeName   = 'System.Array'
    MemberType = 'ScriptMethod'
    MemberName = 'ToUpperRandom'
}

Update-TypeData @updateTypeDataSplat -Value {
    $index = Get-Random -Maximum $this.Length
    $this[$index] = $this[$index].ToUpper()
}

Then you can do something like:
$array1 = @('Car', 'House', 'Computer', 'Phone')
$array1 = $array1 | Get-Random -Count 2
$array1.ToUpperRandom()
$array1

# Car
# PHONE

Another way to do it, using a PowerShell function:
function ToUpperRandom {
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string] $InputObject,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [int] $Count
    )

    begin {
        $i = 0; $ran = Get-Random -Maximum $Count
    }
    process {
        if ($i++ -eq $ran) {
            return $InputObject.ToUpper()
        }

        $InputObject
    }
}

$array1 = @('Car', 'House', 'Computer', 'Phone')
$count = 4
$array1 = $array1 | Get-Random -Count $count | ToUpperRandom -Count $count
$array1

# Phone
# Car
# Computer
# HOUSE


Nice. Just for the sake of it (and for the novelty of writing a function that actually uses blocks, which I rarely do) I rewrote your function to remove the -Count parameter for when there's an unknown number of items arriving in the pipeline, at the cost of "streaming" items to the next element in the pipeline...

To complement @SantiagoSquarzon's answer, I've rewritten his function so as to not need the Count parameter - this has a some pros and cons:

you don't need to know the number of items coming in through the pipeline in advance (no -Count parameter).

your lose the benefit of pipeline chaining because the function has to re-accumulate all items in its process block before it can return any of them in the end block, whereas @SantiagoSquarzon's answer will "stream" items on to the next pipeline element as they get returned from the process block.


There's probably different scenarios where each is better suited...
function ToUpperRandom {
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string] $InputObject
    )
    begin {
        $items = [system.collections.generic.list[string]]::new()
    }
    process {
        # accumulate all of the objects from the pipeline
        $items.Add($InputObject)
    }
    end {
        # uppercase one item at random
        if( $items.Count -gt 0 )
        {
            $rnd = Get-Random -Maximum $items.Count
            $items[$rnd] = $items[$rnd].ToUpperInvariant() 
        }
        # return the collection
        # note - powershell will "unroll" the collection - i.e. automatically enumerate the items
        # and output them one at a time rather than return the collection object itself
        $items
    }
}

And use it like this:
@('Car', 'House', 'Computer', 'Phone') `
    | Get-Random -Count 2 `
    | ToUpperRandom

# Phone
# COMPUTER


Note - I've used ToUpperInvariant - have a read about the difference between ToUpper and ToUpperInvariant and decide which one makes more sense for your use case...
